# Replacing Whole XmlElement with new value 

Tags: c#, xml, c#-2.0

I have got below code in which I am taking html and then reading all the `img` and `a` links. Note this is C# 2.0.

```
string xml = "<xhtml>" + inputXhtml + "</xhtml>";
XmlDocument node = new XmlDocument();
node.LoadXml(xml);
foreach (XmlElement element in TemplateUtilities.SelectNodes(node, "//html:img[@xlink:href]|//html:a[@xlink:href]"))
{
    bool flag = element.LocalName == "img";
    lStrCompLinkText = "";
    XmlAttributeCollection attributes = element.Attributes;
    XmlAttribute namedItem = (XmlAttribute)attributes.GetNamedItem("href", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
    string str2 = namedItem.Value;              
    Component currentObject = engine.GetObject(str2) as Component;
    if (flag)
    {
        element.SetAttribute("src", str2);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (XmlNode xnode in element.ChildNodes)
        {
            lStrCompLinkText = lStrCompLinkText + xnode.OuterXml;
        }   
        string attr = ComponentBase.ComponentHelper.ComponentLinkAttributes(element, engine);       
        string compLink = ComponentBase.ComponentHelper.DisplayPublishedComponentLink(currentObject, lStrCompLinkText, attr, engine, package, pageObject);

        attributes.RemoveNamedItem("href", "http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0");
        //Here I want to replace whole element with the compLink
    }
    attributes.RemoveNamedItem("href", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
    attributes.RemoveNamedItem("type", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
    attributes.RemoveNamedItem("title", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
}
```

Now I want to replcace my element with the new value compLink and add back to the input HTML

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my above problem using below logic:

```
XmlDocument lObjTCDCodeDom = new XmlDocument();
lObjTCDCodeDom.LoadXml("<TCDCode/>");
lObjTCDCodeDom.DocumentElement.InnerText = compLink;
element.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(node.ImportNode(lObjTCDCodeDom.DocumentElement, true), element);
```

and then further wrote the XSLT which check the `<TCDCode/>` and replaces it and then I get actual updated xml.

Answer (score 1):

At the spot where your comment "// Here I want to replace" appears do the following.

Create an XML Document from the contentes of compLink (assuming it's XML).

```
XmlDocument xmlTemp = new XmlDocument();
xmlTemp.loadXml( compLink );
```

Remove the original element from it's parent with the following code

```
XmlNode ndParent = element.ParentNode;
ndParent.RemoveChild( element);
```

Import and append the new xmlTemp to the parent

```
XmlNode ndImport = ndParent.OwnerDocument.ImportNode( xmlTemp.documentElement, true );
ndParent.AppendChild( ndImport.CloneNode( true ) );
```

Comment: Hi William..thanks for your reply!!, I am getting 'link' is an undeclared namespace. Line 1, position 2.' as my compLink variable is having this format <link:binarylink runat="server" publicationuri="tcm:0-233-1" binaryuri="tcm:233-368293" textonfail="True" anchor="" additionalattributes=" target=&quot;_blank&quot; class=&quot;iconDownloadPDF&quot; title=&quot;Road map&quot;">Download a road map (PDF)</link:binarylink> Please suggest!!

Comment: Ah, namespaces, the worst thing ever invented in XML (but that's another story...). I'd try to add the "link" and "tcm" namespaces to the parent document.  Put them in right at the top where you create the the <xhtml> document, for example <xhtml xmlns:tm="url"/>, and get the value of "url" from the source document.